# How to run blocking code from async code that borrows?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

It's well known that async code should not run for long between awaits. Nonetheless, sometimes async code needs to perform long-running operations, like blocking IO. In those cases, it seems the usual recommendation is to use `tokio::task::spawn_blocking` (for example, see [this blog post](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/#what-if-i-want-to-block) from one of the Tokio developers).

The trouble is, as with regular `tokio::task::spawn`, `spawn_blocking` must own all the data it accesses (or it must have `'static` lifetime), even when immediately awaiting it (see [Why does `tokio::spawn` requires a `'static` lifetime if I immediately await it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74865493/why-does-tokiospawn-requires-a-static-lifetime-if-i-immediately-await-it)).

As a result, code like this will not compile:

```rust
fn foo(my_ref: &ExpensiveToClone) {
    // Do some stuff that blocks for IO
}

async fn foo_the_reference(my_ref: &ExpensiveToClone) {
    spawn_blocking(move || {
        foo(my_ref);
    }).await;
}
```

Is there a way to run blocking code from async code without this static lifetime restriction?

Comment: What about [`async-scoped`](https://crates.io/crates/async-scoped) or a similar crate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using tokio, you can use [`tokio::task::block_in_place`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html). It still blocks the thread, but it at least notifies the executor that it will be blocked and should offload its tasks to other threads.

Comment: Note that it is more expensive than `spawn_blocking()`, so you should avoid it unless you have a good reason.

Comment: "It still blocks the thread" - Can you elaborate more on the implications of this in your answer?

Comment: Perhaps @ChayimFriedman can corroborate since its not exactly spelled out in the tokio docs what the exact implications are, but: the way tokio works is to have a set of threads that execute the async tasks; using `spawn_blocking` uses totally different threads while `block_in_place` will "steal" one of the threads dedicated to asyncs tasks temporarily. The broader implications (if I'm correct) that if you do this too much you could end up starving your async tasks.

Comment: After further reading, it sounds like the gotcha is that there are various ways to execute futures concurrently within a single task, e.g. `join!`, `select!`, `StreamExt::for_each_concurrent`, etc., and using `block_in_place` will block the entire task, not just the async function/block where it resides. For example, `join!` polls each of its "child" futures in turn. If one blocks, `join!` is stuck waiting for it to unblock before it can poll the next future. However, anything that has been `spawn`ed can truly run in parallel on a different thread.

Comment: That is very true as well and something to consider